# Electric water heater tank booster

Tags: electrical, water, heater

My tank booster is set to 120 degrees but the water isn’t hot enough. I want to increase the temperature. I tried using the Allen wrench and turning it counter clockwise but it won’t budge. Am I doing something wrong? Can I just increase the temperature on the tank itself or do I need to adjust the booster as well?

Comment: Model number: RE250T6-1NCWW

Comment: It needs regular screwdriver not Allen wrench for temp adjustment

Comment: I know that a regular screwdriver is needed to remove the covers on the tank itself. My Cash Acme Tank Booster Pro is set to 120 degrees and using the Allen wrench to turn it counter clockwise won’t budge. So I’m trying to figure out if I can increase the temperature on the tank itself or do I need to adjust the tank booster gauge as well.

Comment: according to they manual the temperature is adjusted by a screwdriver no force using only two fingers, the very hot setting is clockwise

Comment: A fast search says something about the temp adjust is lockable.  You might need to unlock it first.

Comment: I know that there are 2 panels on the side of the tank that can be removed and then you use a screwdriver to adjust the temperature. My question is. Does the tank booster which is on top of the tank and is set to 120 degrees Need to be adjusted as well?

Comment: First time hearing about tank boosters.  If the cold water goes in the booster first before the tank, then should be able to just raise the tank temp.  If the hot water goes into the booster, then the booster needs adjustment.  120 is considered safe temp to prevent burning of skin, higher temps can burn skin, so children/old folks(hopefully older than me) need watching.

Comment: https://www.cashacme.com/sites/default/files/files/Tank-Booster-Pro-Install-Instructions.pdf See instructions for raising temperature on page 9. Your water heater should be set to 140F, the Tank Booster Pro is default set to 120F and adjustable to 130F after you unlock the temperature adjustment.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some detail about your water heater (type, model numbers) and tank booster (model numbers, purpose, connection diagram). That information belongs in the Question, not in Comments.

Comment: Is this "booster" in the output of the water heater? The name suggests a device that could raise the temperature of the water going into the pipes, but this is not really feasible. Is this a device to lower the temp of the water going into the pipes by feeding in cold water?

Comment: Cash Acme Tank Booster

Comment: Fredric Shope . The link you provided regarding the booster is the one I have. I think my questions are pretty straightforward so I think I will leave them as is. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

The booster is intended to be at a temp lower than your water heater.  It mixes cold water with your tank's hotter water to increase the amount of hot water you can supply.  So the idea is to set your water heater to, say, 140 and then set the booster to 120.  The booster gives you 120 degree water by taking less 140 degree water from the tank.  That said, I suspect your problem may be the booster.  If it is misadjusted (or defective) then you may be getting colder water than you intend out of the heater.

To your question, yes, you absolutely must adjust the booster, the booster is what controls the temperature of water to your home.